# $\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{1-x^2}d(1-x^2)$

Tags: calculus

I think the result should be $ln(|1-x^2|)^\frac{1}{2} + C$.

But the answer is $ln(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2} + C$.

Could you please tell me where the wrong is? I just used the formula table.

Comment: What do you mean by $d(1-x^2)$?

Comment: It is a denotion for substitution.

Comment: You're answer is correct.  The so-called answer is obviously wrong for $|x|>1$.

Comment: @AndiZhang In calculus, one typically uses $dx$ or $dy$ or... as the indication of the integration variable, not of the form you used.  Would you ever expect to see an integral where the integration was denoted $d(\cos(x)/(1 - x^{3/2}))$, for instance?  Of course not.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you very much for your advice. I will never write a integration like this again.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: While it's possible that the given answer is wrong, it's also possible that there's some context we're not seeing that restricts the domain of the function to $|x|<1$.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $1-x^2=u$ and $d(1-x^2)=du$. Integral becomes:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u}d(u)=\frac{1}{2}\ln |u| +c=\frac{1}{2}\ln |1-x^2|+c= \ln \sqrt{|1-x^2|} +c$$

You must be careful what is inside the $d()$. You can differentiate the inside of the $d()$ and take it out such as:

$$d(f(x))=f'(x)dx$$

Comment: $\int \frac{dt}{t}=\log |t|+C \ne \log t+C$.  Try integrating $\int_{-2}^{-1}\frac{dx}{x}$ using your answer, which omits absolute values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the formula table shows that $\int\frac{1}{x}dx$ should be $ln|x|$, could you please tell me why the | | is  eliminated here?

Comment: Because I made a mistake